# ActiveX control '971127bb-259f-48c2-bd75-5f97a3331551' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment

Tags: c#, multithreading, activex

I'm creating an rdp application, but I keep the error stated above. I've tried adding `[STATHREAD]` before my load method, and I've tried this:

```
    [System.STAThread]
    private void rdp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread a = new System.Threading.Thread(rdp_connect);
        a.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        a.IsBackground = true;
        a.Start();
    }
```

rdp_connect method:

```
[STAThread]
        public void rdp_connect()
        {
            axMsRdpClient2a1.Server = mainform.addr;
            axMsRdpClient2a1.UserName = mainform.uname;
            IMsTscNonScriptable enc_connection = (IMsTscNonScriptable)axMsRdpClient2a1.GetOcx();
            enc_connection.ClearTextPassword = mainform.pass;
            try
            {
                axMsRdpClient2a1.Connect();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not connect.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
```

I've also noticed that the designer for the form shows when the error happens, I don't think that's important, though. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: It is important.  You must use the `this.DesignMode` property to prevent code from running when the UserControl is used in design mode.  The Load event also fires at design time, you do *not* want to start a thread when that happens.  Directly referencing *mainform* is certainly something else you'd never want to do.  Use properties instead.

Comment: Ok. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply [STAThread] to an arbitrary method (well, you can, but it does not do anything). Here is what MSDN tells about [STAThread]:

Apply this attribute to the entry point method (the Main() method in C# and Visual Basic). It has no effect on other methods. To set the apartment state of threads you start in your code, use the Thread.SetApartmentState method before starting the thread.